# Missing elements in picture

Tags: diagrams

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
 \centering
 \setlength{\unitlength}{0.1\textwidth}
  \begin{picture}(5,5)
    \put(4.17,3.5){$x$}
    \includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{rys}
  \end{picture}
\end{figure}
```

When I typeset it using dvi, the letter x and picture rys appear but when I use pdflatex, x disappear.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that picture `rys` is overlapping that letter. Try to wrap picture into `\put` command as your letter is. Then you can easily change its coordinates.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
 \centering
 \setlength{\unitlength}{0.1\textwidth}
  \begin{picture}(5,5)
    \put(4.17,3.5){$x$}
    \put(-5,-2){\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{rys}}
  \end{picture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to reverse the order (which matters):

```
\begin{picture}(5,5)
\put(4.17,3.5){$x$}
```

That will *always* put the `$x$` in **front** of the graphic. But then you will need to change the coordinates for `\put(4.17,3.5){$x$}` (most particularly the x coordinate -- try -4.17 for a start) to place `$x$` where you need it to be. I can't be more specific without a MWE.